# OpenSSH 8.8 talking to 5.3 - no matching host key type -- despite common recommended solution

Tags: ssh, openssh

Recently upgraded small image from Fedora 36 to 37 and immediately started getting this error below:

If tried many alterations of the following command (the commonly recommended solution) and it still fails.  (minor removal of identifying info)

Adding output from -vvv, same problem, just more details added.

```
ssh -vvv -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss,ssh-rsa oldhost
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/xxxxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/xxxxx/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host oldhost originally oldhost
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host oldhost originally oldhost
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/xxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/xxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "oldhost" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup oldhost:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to oldhost [10.20.30.40] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to oldhost:22 as 'user'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match)
Unable to negotiate with 10.68.90.165 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss
```

So even though I'm adding the -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss,ssh-rsa argument to match the oldhost offering, it still fails.
I've tried just +ssh-dss, without the +, etc.  Nothing seems to allow the connection.

There are other servers also on 5.3 that have RSA host keys and they work.  It is only the few that have dss keys that fail.

Any thoughts?
BF

Comment: Try stepping up the verbosity to `-vvv`, iirc it will show all the information about which algorithms are being considered by both the server and the client. You can also look at `ssh-audit` and compare the output to `ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss,ssh-rsa -G oldhost | sort`. (The `-G` outputs the client config for that host, but it's not sorted, so `| sort` on the end makes it easier to look for the stuff you're interested in.)

Comment: I updated the description to include the -vvv output.  It still doesn't really reveal the problem to me, maybe someone more familiar with this output can spot the problem.  Also I discovered Fedora 36 had the same version of OpenSSH 8.8 as 37 (and it worked fine with the common fix).

Comment: Do you have a DSA host key under `/etc/ssh`? On my Debian system to enable `ssh-dss` I had not only to add the key type to `sshd_config` with `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss` I also had to re-enable the host key file itself, `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key`. You'll be different because RedHat isn't Debian but it may get you on the right path

Comment: The oldserver has a file /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
and corresponding entry in sshd_config.

The more I think on this, the same version on Fedora 36 worked to the same servers (no changes there).  It seems like F37 build is buggy, more handicapped, etc.